# Paypal Mobile payments -from with a Phonegap HTML5 IOS app

Tags: ios, html, cordova, paypal

Has anybody had any success in setting up Paypal payments that will run within a Phonegap IOS app?

Our brief is to allow a client to setup payments within the app via the CMS.

My method currently is to populate a standard buy button form which is loaded into the app via json - This is triggered when user makes a booking - they would be sent outside the app to a Paypal page running in Safari - when the payment is completed Paypal will re-direct to a secure server page - which will receive the transaction ID from paypal - de-crypt this (via paypal supplied code) to receive payment info - store relevant transaction data in the DB and then trigger the app to re-open and ideally trigger a function inside the app which will refresh the order based on data received from the CMS.

Sounds very convoluted -  but due to the restrictions of opening the paypal form within the app - and the fact that we need to make buy buttons on the fly for a wide range of users - this is the best I can come up with.

Does anyone have any better suggestions / tried and tests solutions!?

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm trying to figure out what provides best experience in terms of payments in PhoneGap on iOS...

[image]

Speaking of PayPal:
Just tried their workflow and I must admit it works out of the box really well with one BUT: return URL brought me to an external site, all withing context of Cordova app. *(it can be probably fixed by [overriding default url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537020/paypal-button-adding-variable-to-return-url), [to native app](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html), [which is detected here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200), or maybe using [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html))*

> when the payment is completed Paypal will re-direct to a secure server page - which will receive the transaction ID from paypal

Please see the difference:

- https://www.paypal.com/pdt - Payment Data Transfer - cannot rely, user can just close the browser (close the app in this particular case)
- https://www.paypal.com/ipn - Instant Payment Notification - automated post to your backend, much better indication if the payment was completed

*(I'll fiddle more in this area and share findings if they are relevant)*

Comment: Cool cheers Michal, are you using the buy button method here then?  I guess that takes you outside the app to complete any payments?  Cheers

Comment: Ask computer, give it a try :) Actually PayPal login is displayed within the app. It was the **return url** that caused issues - it uses absolute URL and rather than see 3 buttons upon successful payments I was redirected to some other site, all within Cordova app (edited answer for clarity). It was getting late last night, Today will try similar trick with InAppBrowser...

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with a bit of Objective-C, you could take a crack at a PhoneGap plugin for the new [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/). You could look at the [card.io PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/card.io) as a model.