# Paypal button with parameter

Tags: paypal

I want to create a paypal button accepting one extra parameter coming from the checkout page where the payment button will be placed.

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537020/paypal-button-adding-variable-to-return-url), but it won't work *(the return URL does not contain the custom parameter after payment is done)*.

Note to possible security issue: It's not important if the user can change the parameter or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send custom values like below, 
Example 1 For sending a PHP varaible

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$twitId;?>">
```

Example 2 For sending a fixed variable

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="mycustomvalue">
```

Example 3

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="3862463">
```

Please follow the below link, 
http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php